# rosserial - Arduino Uno vs Duemilanove Serial_node

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Normally i use arduino duemilanove for some research projects and it never caused any problems on the serial connection using the serial_node, but when i use the same code on the arduino uno, i always get the error: "Lost sync with device". But when i push the reset button on the arduino uno board, the serial_node connection is established.

Should i have to setup something on the arduino uno, to solve this problem ? am i missing something?

Serial port:
Arduino Duemilanove -> /dev/ttyUSB0
Arduino UNO         -> /dev/ttyACM0

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11514/rosserial---arduino-uno-vs-duemilanove-serial_node/) by [Andre Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1209/andre-araujo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-10-13**:
It's worth noting that the Duemilanove uses an FTDI chip for USB-Serial, while the Uno uses an Atmega8U2 programmed to be a USB-serial converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We solved this one offline, I'm posting the solution here for future reference:

We applied a patch to work with Unos (which have a slower start up time), but it was after the 0.1.0 release. If you are using an Arduino Uno, please use a source checkout of 0.2.0 (debs will be released shortly).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) on 2013-07-10**:
Hey, I'm having a similar problem and am interested in your solution - could you elaborate on the steps to fix this?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-07-10**:
I honestly don't even recall, as this was 2yrs ago, perhaps take a look at the commit history for rosserial around that time.